# Example for Parquet Avro Projected Materialization (showing a 1-* nested projection)

Tags: java, scala, avro, parquet

How do I materialise a subset of a schema out of an avro (or whatever) encoded parquet file ? (not much documentation is available)

Looking through the source code now and i'll probably be answering my own question :D

**edit: [according to this](https://github.com/Parquet/parquet-mr/blob/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/parquet/hadoop/ParquetInputFormat.java)**

```
/**
 * The input format to read a Parquet file.
 *
 * It requires an implementation of {@link ReadSupport} to materialize the records.
 *
 * The requestedSchema will control how the original records get projected by the loader.
 * It must be a subset of the original schema. Only the columns needed to reconstruct the records with the requestedSchema will be scanned.
 *
 * @author Julien Le Dem
 *
 * @param <T> the type of the materialized records
 */
```

Seems I need to create an Avro class with a subset of the fields (or a subclass or something) with a corresponding object to dematerialise to. Convoluted.

I'll stick to dematerialising all 10 gigs of data before I begin experimenting with this :D If someone wants to answer the question (with a fleshed out example) go ahead.